# How do you use become when invoking a role in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

How do you `become` a user when using a role in ansible?

For example, how would I install nodejs as root using the `geerlingguy.nodejs` role from ansible galaxy? Here is the relevant portion of what I have:

```
roles:
  - geerlingguy.nodejs
    become: yes
```

But that produces `ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML` on the YAML file.

Comment: Clearly invalid YAML syntax..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a solution, which in retrospect is obvious from the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles)

```
roles:
    - role: geerlingguy.nodejs
      become: yes
```

This can also be written as:

```
roles:
    - { role: geerlingguy.nodejs, become: yes }
```

The part that was not obvious before to this ansible newbie was the alternate json-like syntax used in the documentation when it states "Also, should you wish to parameterize roles, by adding variables, you can do so, like this:"

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - common
    - { role: foo_app_instance, dir: '/opt/a',  app_port: 5000 }
```

I spent way too long figuring this out, so hopefully this answer will help someone else.

Comment: Warning: as noted [here](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/126#issuecomment-402790323), setting become on a role is not limited to that role and bleeds over into subsiquent roles.  Definitely not the intent that I wanted when I was trying to do the same thing as the original question.

Comment: In fact that comment in the Github issue relates to using become on tasks, not roles. If you set become: yes on one role, the following one doesn't automatically get it. Just tried it while looking at this SO question and thought I would clarify that.